# TypeError when passing mocked object to parent constructor with PHPUnit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

In my project, I have the following structure where `Foo` (subject of tests) inherit `ParentFoo` and `A` implements `AInterface`.

The `ParentFoo` constructor receives an instance of `AInterface`. The `Foo` constructor needs to execute some code and receive an instance of `A`.

```php
class Foo extends ParentFoo
{
    public function __constructor(A $a)
    {
        // ...
        parent::__construct($a);
    } 
}

class ParentFoo
{
    public function __constructor(AInterface $a)
    {
        // ...
    }
}


class A  implements AInterface
{ 
    // ...
}
```

In the tests, I mock the object `A` - which make PHPUnit generate the `Mock_A_62d11d77` object - and I pass it to the `Foo` constructor.

```php
class FooTest extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testFooMethod()
    {
        $mockA = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(A::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $foo = new Foo($mockA);   // error stack begins here <
        // ...
    }
}
```

However, it is returning the following error:

```sh
TypeError: Argument 1 passed to ParentFoo::__construct() must be an instance of AInterface, instance of Mock_A_62d11d77 given
```

Does anyone know if I should mock differently or something else?

Comment: Please provide information about which version of PHP and PHPUnit you are using.

Comment: I am using  **PHP 7.4.5** and **PHPUnit 9.1.4**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot reproduce your problem:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
interface AnInterface
{
}

class AnInterfaceImplementation implements AnInterface
{
}

class ParentClass
{
    public function __constructor(AnInterface $i)
    {
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass
{
    public function __constructor(AnInterface $i)
    {
        parent::__construct($i);
    } 
}

final class Test extends PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase
{
    public function testOne(): void
    {
        $i = $this->createStub(AnInterfaceImplementation::class);

        $o = new ChildClass($i);
    }
}
```

```
$ phpunit Test.php
PHPUnit 9.1.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

R                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 00:00.022, Memory: 6.00 MB

There was 1 risky test:

1) Test::testOne
This test did not perform any assertions

/home/sb/Test.php:27

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Risky: 1.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem was in the namespaces on our project. The type hint in the `ParentClass` was wrong.  Thanks again.

Comment: I got a warning using the code above because `__constructor` should be `__construct`. But anyway it helped find the answer. Thanks